# Rails Query Active Record By Pairs OR'ed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, active-record-query

I have an API that looks like...

```
get(not_unique_id:, pairs: [])
```

...where pairs can look like `[{ foo: 1, bar: 'a' }, { foo: 2, bar: 'b' }]` and I want to write a query that will find all entries for the given non unique id, filtered by the pairs, i.e. ...

```
Thing.where(not_unique_id: not_unique_id)
# need help here -> .where("(foo = #{pairs.first[:foo]} AND bar = #{pairs.first[:bar]}) OR (foo = #{pairs.second[:foo]} AND bar = #{pairs.second[:bar]}) OR ...")
.map # or whatever else I want to do
```

I need a way to perform this `foo` AND `bar` comparison for each entry in my input pairs, OR'ed together to return all results that are have the not unique ID AND one of the pairs' values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`or`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-or) to chain together multiple `where` clauses with `OR`s:

```
Record.where(a: 'b').or(Record.where(c: 'd')).to_sql
# => select * from records where (a = 'b' OR c = 'd')
```

Using this and your array of conditions, you can provide a starting "seed" of `Record.all` to a `reduce` call and chain multiple successive conditions by `or`ing them onto the scope:

```
conditions = [{ foo: 1, bar: 'a' }, { foo: 2, bar: 'b' }]

records = conditions.inject(Record.all) do |scope, condition|
            scope.or(Record.where(condition))
          end
```

Comment: What's more, if this is a scope on `Record`, then you can basically remove all the references to "Record" in your answer. That reduces it to the very terse:

`conditions.inject(all) { |scope, condition| scope.or(where(condition)) }`

Comment: @Glyoko You shouldn't do that. If you're providing a class-level scope, you must return `conditions.inject(self) { ...  }`. Don't discard whatever conditions have already been applied to the scope by using `all`.

Comment: Whoops, you're right, that should be `self`. Thanks @meagar.